# OpenOffice: different font weights

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, libreoffice, openoffice

I'm using OO for Mac, although I've had this same problem with LibreOffice and I think maybe MS Office too.

And the problem is that, for fonts that have a lot of different weights, I can only use either 'regular' or 'bold / italic' in OpenOffice.

E.g. if I use the font 'Swiss 721' in any Adobe software, it gives me a bunch of different weights such as thin, regular, heavy etc. But in OO all I get is just 'Swiss 721':

[image]

Normally I would be able to at least make it bold using OO too, but for some reason I can't even do that, if I try making it bold it simply gives me an outline version of the font!:

[image]

Comment: In your Windows\Fonts directory how many Swiss 721 fonts files are there? What are there names? Can you [edit] and add to the question?

Comment: Some TTF fonts are *variable*, i.e. a single file contains info to change weight, kerning, etc. *However, not all software and operating systems can make use of this feature.* See https://www.sitepoint.com/variable-fonts-introduction/